# Teleconference between three or more people on Skype

Tags: windows, skype, telephony, conferencing

Skype is great for 2-way video conferencing, but for my work I need to be able to patch in more than two people to the video conference.

Is it possible to hook up three or more people into a Skype conference?

Or should I look to something else instead which would be as reliable and of high quality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We've used [WebEx](http://www.webex.com) at work with good results in the past. Supports both video conferencing as well as desktop sharing between clients. People can even dial in to a conference over the phone if they don't have a microphone.

Since you've said this is work-related, the cost at $49/month may not be too bad.

Comment: +1 Nice!  Looks like they're set to bury GoToMeeting... same price, but with videoconferencing!  Bit of a no-brainer, isn't it?

Comment: + Answer credit - I think this is the one we're going to use.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Actually [Skype](http://www.skype.com/intl/en/get-skype/on-your-computer/windows/beta/) themselves have now come up with a multi-user (up to 9) video conf.  Tested it last week and it looks fine.  At this writing it's in Beta, with a "free trial", though I can't see how they can charge for it while it's still in Beta...

Comment: Up to 250 now...

Answer (score 3):

http://tinychat.com/

It's a web app so no software to install.  It includes a chatroom feature and offers you option to record the conference.  I find it pretty cool.

Answer (score 1):

Where this is an older question... newer advancements have been made in this arena.  [Google Plus](https://plus.google.com/) now offers "Hangouts" where you can invite a group of people to a video-conference enabled chat session and interact freely over the web.  It's free... and it works quite well.

Answer (score 0):

ooVoo is an iChat-like video conferencing and chat tool for Windows, loaded with useful, powerful tools that make it a viable alternative for small work groups using conference calls and screen-sharing applications.

[Homepage](http://www.oovoo.com/)

Comment: I tried ooVoo a while back. It has a very annoying interface, much too noisy, huge time lag, unreliable service.  I uninstalled it in disgust.