# What options do I have to setup a recurring video conference with my family?

Tags: skype, calendar, google-calendar, conferencing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What 3+ user teleconference software do you recommend?](https://superuser.com/questions/69518/what-3-user-teleconference-software-do-you-recommend)

I want to setup a recurring video conference with my family, so we can meet bi-weekly at a scheduled time since we are all separated by distance.

We all have Google accounts(Google+, Google Calendar), Skype, iPhones with Facetime, and either Windows 7 laptops with Mic/Cam, or Macbooks with Mic/Cam.

I would be open to having us all sign up for new accounts if some other service offers this, but I am hoping for something that can be used with Google Calendar and either Google+ Chat or Skype.

Comment: @random - This is not a duplicate. The other question has no requirement around setting up a recurring meeting or invite, which is what I am asking about here. That question is also asking about "teleconferencing" which is actually different then video conferencing.

Comment: It was either a duplicate with answers or closed as non-constructive for what is basically a shopping question